# Element is not clickable at point, ruby

Tags: jquery, ruby, selenium, webdriver, element

I am using Rspec, Selenium Webdriver, Ruby, Mac OSx When I execute script for Firefox, everything goes smooth.   When I do change to Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130, there is error

> ```
> >      unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (385, 575). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ajax-progress
> > ajax-progress-throbber">...</div>
> >        (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.130)
> >        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322455 (ae8db840dac8d0c453355d3d922c91adfb61df8f),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.4
> > x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
> ```

I tried to add wait time, also with research, I found out for Java there is possibility to do with JavascriptExecutor.

Would possible to do something in Ruby?

```
And(/^User select account and telephone to upgrade$/) do
  @profile = get_account("consumer.postpaid.user9")
  RubyHelper.wait_js_load_in_seconds(5)
  accounts = @driver.find_elements(:css => "p.account-number")
  accounts.each do |account|
    account.click if account.text.include? @profile.ban
    account
   # scroll the element into view, then return its location
   # build_page.choose_account_button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    build_page.choose_account_button.click
  end
  RubyHelper.wait_js_load_in_seconds(6)
  elements = @driver.find_elements(:css => "h3.phone-number")
  elements.each do |element|
    element.click if element.text == @profile.phone
    element
  end
```

Fails in build_page.choose_account_button.click

However, previous line return coordinates.

UPDATE

I got solution to this issue

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html

```
el = driver.find_element(:id, "some_id")
driver.action.click(el).perform
```

Comment: If you take your selector in chrome tools and manually ask for it, does it return what you expect? Seems like a timing issue, but I'd expect that more from FF than Chrome

Comment: I tried adding sleep time, did not help. I tend to find that issues raise when each do used

Comment: Can we see your code???

Comment: you can try to do findElementBySelector , then in JS i would write driver.actions().mouseDown(element).perform(). I had those trouble back then as well

Comment: I am on Rspec, Ruby. Looking for syntax. Element actually lids up upon selecting desired phone number

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some ajax calls going on there, preventing the element to be clicked. Whilst adding waits will solve your problem initially, consider adding a **wait_for_ajax** method into your click method.

For example:

```
def wait_for_ajax(timeout = 30)
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new timeout: timeout
  wait.until { @driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0") == true }
end
```

The benefit of this is that you're not hardcoding in waits which is just *bad*.